# Which Platforms are supported for the IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK?

Tags: ibm-sbt

Which Platforms are supported for the IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK? Can I run the SDK on an IBM Domino/XWork server?

Comment: I'm assuming you already knew the answer to this one? You might want to be careful about posting questions and creating tags just to build a community. It sometimes doesn't turn out all that well. I didn't downvote nor vote to close, but it's obvious from this and a previous question that it's not going down well. Perhaps discuss on Meta first how you can get this off to a better start.

Comment: Yes, I certainly agree that I should have done this differently. This is my first time that I wanted to create a new tag and it wasn't as straight forward as I had hoped. Over the next days more people will use the new tag with actual questions. So things will get better. We need a new tag so that people can actually find the content they are looking for.

Comment: Best thing indeed is to let things grow organically. Just announce that you're active on SO and will look for related questions. Answering actual questions is better (and better received) than starting to post pseudo-questions, which people will certainly notice. And while in this case Per answered, the association between the two of you is not all that hidden. Such behaviour is easily mistaken for spam or other dubious activities. Just let it grow on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following platforms are supported:

- WebSphere Application Server 7
- WebSphere Portal 8
- Domino Server 8.5
- Tomcat 7

So yes, you can use the SDK on an IBM Domino/XWork Server.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK should work with minimal amount of work on any J2EE server.

The WebSphere Application Server, Portal 8, Domino 8.5, Tomcat 7 are the tested versions.